# Amazon EC2 Instance running Ubuntu doesn't connect with non ec2-user

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 10.04.
I created my new user with `sudo useradd -d /some/path new_user`.

Using the new_user, I created a new rsa key, using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` in the `/some/path`.

I combined the files to generate the authorized_keys file:

```
cat .ssh/id*.pub > .ssh/authorized_keys
```

So, I generated a ppk file with Filezilla and successfully connected to it.

But, one day after, I tried to connect again (with this ppk generated and my new_user), but it doesn't work.

I tried to recreate a new rsa key, just like before, but it still doesn't connect.

Wondering if there was a problem with the new_user created, I created another one (new_user2) and its rsa key. Again, it doesn't work.

At login time server says 'server refused our key' and no supported authentication method available popup.

The ec2-user named ubuntu (default user) works ok.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

I used [this tutorial](http://blog.sofasurfer.org/2011/07/16/ubuntu-ec2-add-new-admin-user/) as reference.

I still tried to use [this another one](http://codingthis.com/platforms/creating-new-linux-users-and-login-keys-on-amazon-ec2/), but I came across the same issue.

Below is my putty.log file after this issue:

```
    =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2013.08.22 09:39:08    =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
login as: new_user
Server refused our key
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the ssh (or putty) logs to the ec2 instance? for ssh, just use `ssh -v new_user@your-ec2-ip`

Comment: @number5, I updated it with my putty.log. It helps?

Comment: hmm, I should say I need the event log e.g. http://static.thegeekstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/putty-event-log.png try this: When you are logged-in to a PuTTY SSH session, right mouse-click on the PuTTY window title, which will display PuTTY menu. Select ‘Event Log’ menu-item, which will display the following PuTTY event log window. then copy and paste in your question

Answer (score 0):

No need to make things complicated. No need to use a new key.
Login using 'ubuntu' then in terminal type

```
$ su - user2  (or whatever you named it to)
Password:     (enter the password)
```

Hope that helped :)